# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in _______ on line 20

Tags: php

Here is my code and I don't know how to fix it, please help thanks! here is the par where the error is, it's on the line with $value.

```
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

    if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use '. DB_NAME . ': ' .mysqli_error());
      } 

    $value = $_POST ('Name');
    $value2 = $_POST ('Email');
    $query= "INSERT INTO person (Name, Email) VALUES ('$value',      '$value2' )";

    if (!mysqli_query($query)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
```

Comment: You haven't defined $_POST as a function?

Comment: Please provide more info (minimal, complete, verifiable code) and error stack trace

Answer (score 3):

You've got a syntax error on these lines:

```
$value = $_POST ('Name');
$value2 = $_POST ('Email');
```

`$_POST` is an array, so you need to use square brackets to access it, like so:

```
$value = $_POST['Name'];
$value2 = $_POST['Email'];
```

Using regular brackets tells PHP that you're trying to call a function with the value in the variable `$_POST`. Because it's an array, it's throwing an error.

I should also add that you've got a serious SQL injection vulnerability. See this answer for more details: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Also include about `mysql_error` to change this to `mysqli_error`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
$value = $_POST['Name'];
$value2 = $_POST['Email'];
```

Notice the square brackets for $_POST instead of the parentheses you had.